# Python или триггеры в mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Имеется база данных [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), там есть таблица с вводом сжигаемого топлива и коэффициент выбросов. Данные вводятся через поле запроса на сайте. Нужно их умножить, чтобы получить количество выбросов с одного предприятия, и потом просуммировать все выбросы. Подскажите, как лучше поступить. При получении ответа в питоне умножить и потом ввести в таблицу, или создать триггер при обновлении в `MySQL`?

Comment: Зависит от созданной структуры хранения и идеологии поддержки продукта. Если используете современные фреймворки, то с поддержанием триггеров у них есть определённые проблемы... хотя я вообще не понимаю, зачем нужны переопределённые данные.

Comment: Просто нужна база данных, в которых хранятся количества сжигаемого топлива и коэффициенты от видов топлива. Нужно просто выводить произведение этих элементов и суммировать. Если бы можно было как-то по-другому, то был бы рад услышать варианты

Comment: Храните только исходные данные. А умножение и суммирование выполняйте в запросе, когда эти данные потребовались.